# Not able to access to CVS repositories from remote computer

Tags: cvs

I could not access the CVS repositories which has the link as :

```
~project/directory/to/of/cvs/project
```

I would like to access it from remote computer.What can be the suitable command to  access it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up some sort of server to provide remote access.  A couple of the options include:

- using rsh or ssh to access the repository
- using the cvs pserver to access the repository

You'll find more details in the cvs documentation at [CVS Remote Repository Manual Section](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS--Concurrent%20Versions%20System%20v1.12.12.1%3A%20The%20Repository#SEC26)